# PHP - Facebook Opengraph - querying without a user logged in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using the PHP SDK of Facebook to retrieve all sorts of information.
If you don't know, facebook keeps a temporary link for every video hosted on it and that link becomes inactive after a few days.
Therefor, I query FB using PHP with a vid to get it's url.
The problem is that I have to do that action even if a current user that's viewing my page isn't connected to my app.
Do you have any creative solution for me to query FB with a vid (video ID) even if the current user that's browsing my website isn't connected to my app?
(I could use an existing user token but now I have to control which tokens are alive and so on...)

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of API call do you make to query a Video?

Comment: a simple query ... SELECT title,vid,src,src_hq,thumbnail_link,length FROM video WHERE vid=X

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to query publicly accessible videos use your App Access token. Unlike an access token you obtain from a user, your app access token will not expire unless you reset your secret key. Take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/